# Y86 Processor in C help! Stuck on the loader.c file

Tags: c, simulator, y86

This is gonna be a bit of a large question (at least for me it seems) so bear with me. We're making a y86 simulator in C and this part of the assignment is supposed to open a file, load it into memory, perform a dump, and exit. The main method is provided to do these things, we're just supposed to create the loader.c and loader.h files to actually do the loading. The load function returns true(1) if the load was successful (input file was free of errors) and false(0) otherwise. Right now, I'm stuck on the load function, and I think the issue is on around line 58-67 of loader.c. I'm not calling the method properly, but I cannot figure out how to format the numbers properly. This is the first time I'm working in C, so it's still a rather confusing for me. If needed I can provide more code. So far I've included loader.c, loader.h, memory.c, and memory.h. Bool.h is included, but it's just a typedef for true-false so I figured I could leave it out. I apologize if this is a bit much, but I'm completely stumped and I don't know where else to go. Thank you so much in advance for any help given, it will be greatly appreciated!

loader.c:

```
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <string.h>
3   #include "loader.h"
4   #include "bool.h"
5   #include "memory.h"
6  
7   bool checkAddressFormat (char addressArray[]);
8   bool checkDataFormat(char dataArray[]);
9   bool isDigit(char character); 
10  bool checkLine(char inputLine[]);
11 
12  int load(int argc, char *argv[]){
13 
14      if (argc != 2){
15          printf("file opening failed \nusage: yess <filename>.yo\n");
16          return 0;
17      }
18      else{
19          //Checks that all the files exist
20          FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r" );
21          char* ext;
22          ext = strrchr(argv[1], '.'); //Grab extension
23          if (file == 0 || strcmp(ext,".yo") != 0) {
24              printf("file opening failed \nusage: yess <filename>.yo\n");
25              return 0;
26          }
27         else{
28             char inputLine[250]; //The current line being used
29             int intLine[250];
30             int ch;
31             int i;
32             int j;
33             int k;
34             int m;
35             bool lineCheck;
36             bool memError = FALSE;
37             int byteAddress;
38             int lineNumber = 1;
39             
40             ch = fgetc(file); //Grab first character
41             while (!feof(file)) //While file is not empty
42             {
43                 while(ch != '\n'){
44                     inputLine[i] = ch;
45                     intLine[i] = ch;
46                     ch = fgetc(file);
47                 }
48                 char addressString[4];
49                 addressString[3] = '\0';
50                 for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){ //Creates char array of address on current line.
51                      addressString[j] = inputLine[j+4];
52                 }
53                 byteAddress = atoi(addressString); //Turns the array into an int to pass to putByte
54 
55                 unsigned char dataString[12];
56                 for(k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
57                      dataString[k] = (unsigned char)intLine[k+9];
58                 }
59 
60                 if(checkLine(inputLine) == FALSE){
61                     printf("Error on line %d:\n",lineNumber);
62                     printf("%s\n",inputLine);
63                     return 0;
64                 }
65                 
66                 else{
67                     for(m = 0; m < 250; m++) {
68                         putByte(byteAddress, dataString[m], &memError);
69                     }
70                     printf("call putByte");
71                 }
72 
73                 for(i = 0; i < 250; i++){
74                     inputLine[i] = ' ';
75                     intLine[i] = ' ';
76                 }
77                 printf("clear arrays");
78                 lineNumber++;
79                 ch = fgetc(file);
80             }
81         }
82         close(file);
83      }
84      return 1;
85  }
86 
87  bool checkLine(char inputLine[]){
88      
89      if(checkDataFormat(inputLine) == FALSE || checkAddressFormat(inputLine) == FALSE){
90          return FALSE;
91      }
92      else if(inputLine[22] != '|'){
93          return FALSE;
94      }
95      else {
96          return TRUE;
97      }
98 
99  }
100 bool checkDataFormat(char dataArray[]) {
101     int i;
102     bool temp;
103     int counter = 0;
104     for(i = 9; i <= 20; i++) {
105         temp = isDigit(dataArray[i]);
106         if(temp  == TRUE){
107             counter++;
108         }
109     }
110     if(counter > 12){
111         return FALSE;
112     }
113     else{
114         return TRUE;
115     }
116 }
117
118 bool checkAddressFormat(char addressArray[]) {
119     if(isDigit(addressArray[2]) == FALSE || isDigit(addressArray[4]) == FALSE || isDigit(addressArray[5])  == FALSE || isDigit(addressArray[6]) == FALSE)
120         return FALSE;
121     if(addressArray[3] != 'x')
122         return FALSE;
123     if(addressArray[7] != ':')
124         return FALSE;
125     else
126         return TRUE;
127 }
128
129 bool isDigit(char character) {
130     if(character == '0' || character == '1' || character == '2' || character == '3' ||
131        character == '4' || character == '5' || character == '6' || character == '7' ||
132        character == '8' || character == '9' || character == 'a' || character == 'b' ||
133       character == 'c' || character == 'd' || character == 'e' || character == 'f')
134       return TRUE;
135    else
136        return FALSE;
137}
138
```

loader.h:

```
1    #ifndef LOADER_H
2    #define LOADER_H
3
4    int load(int argc, char *argv[]);
5
6    #endif
```

memory.c:

```
1   #define MEMSIZE 1024     //1024 words of memory
2   #ifndef MEMORY_H
3   #define MEMORY_H
4   #include "bool.h"
5 
6   static unsigned int memArray[MEMSIZE];
7 
8 
9   unsigned int fetch(int address, bool * memError){
10   
11      if(address < 0 || address > 1024)
12          (*memError) = TRUE;
13      else{
14          (*memError) = FALSE;
15          return memArray[address];
16      }
17  }
18
19  void store(int address, unsigned int value, bool * memError){
20      if(address < 0 || address > 1024)
21          (*memError) = TRUE;
22      else{
23          (*memError) = FALSE;
24          memArray[address] = value;
25      }
26  }
27
28  unsigned char getByte(int byteAddress, bool * memError){
29      if(byteAddress < 0 || byteAddress > 4095){
30          (*memError) = TRUE;
31          return 0;
32      }
33      else{
34          (*memError) = FALSE;
35          int wordAddress = fetch((byteAddress/4), memError);
36          char * x = (char*)&wordAddress;
37          char temp = x[(byteAddress%4)];
38          return temp;
39      }
40  }
41  void putByte(int byteAddress, unsigned char value, bool * memError){
42      if(byteAddress < 0 || byteAddress > 4095)
43          (*memError) = TRUE;
44      else{
45          (*memError) = FALSE;
46          int wordAddress = fetch((byteAddress/4), memError);
47          char * x = (char*)&wordAddress;
48          x[(byteAddress%4)] = value;
49          store(byteAddress/4, wordAddress, memError);
50      }
51  }
52  void clearMemory(){
53
54      int i;
55      for(i=0;i<MEMSIZE;i++){
56          memArray[i] = 0;
57      }
58
59  }
60  //Address must be multiple of 4
61  unsigned int getWord(int byteAddress, bool * memError){
62
63      if(byteAddress < 0 || byteAddress > 4095 || (byteAddress%4) != 0){
64          (*memError) = TRUE;
65          return 0;
66      }
67      else{
68          int word = fetch(byteAddress/4, memError);
69          (*memError) = FALSE;
70          return word;
71      }
72  }
73  //Address must be multiple of 4
74  void putWord(int byteAddress, unsigned int value, bool * memError){
75
76     if(byteAddress < 0 || byteAddress > 4095 || (byteAddress%4) != 0){
77          (*memError) = TRUE;
78      }
79      else{
80          store((byteAddress/4), value, memError);
81          (*memError) = FALSE;
82      }
83   
84
85  }
86  #endif
87
88
```

memory.h:

```
1   #define MEMSIZE 1024     //1024 words of memory
2   #ifndef MEMORY_H
3   #define MEMORY_H
4 
5   unsigned int fetch(int address, bool * memError);
6   void store(int address, unsigned int value, bool * memError);
7   unsigned char getByte(int byteAddress, bool * memError);
8   void putByte(int byteAddress, unsigned char value, bool * memError);
9   void clearMemory();
10  unsigned int getWord(int byteAddress, bool * memError);
11  void putWord(int byteAddress, unsigned int value, bool * memError);
12  #endif
```

Comment: What error exactly are you observing? And what have you tried to debug it?

Comment: I'm getting a segmentation fault, and the only form of debugging I've done is adding print statements, although with that error, I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: You should examine your arrays carefully then. By far, the most common error is that either (a) they aren't long enough, or (b) you are calling a function that assumes your string/array is zero (null) terminated, but the zero hasn't been added. A string in C is null terminated for any C string functions to work. A quick inspecting of some of your string copy loops indicates that you might be missing null terminations.

Comment: I should also add that when I compile this, I get these errors: loader.c: 60 warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast loader.c: 69: warning passing argument 2 of 'putByte' makes integer from pointer without a cast memory.h:8: note: expected 'unsigned char' but argument is of type 'unsigned char *'. I'll add this to the post.

Comment: How is it that you're running the code and getting a segfault if it doesn't compile? See my answer, which addresses that particular error.

Comment: I changed the code in the initial post to reflect your answer, is that in reference to what you meant? I realized I had included a line that didn't need to exist (it was from a previous failed attempt). I meant the previous line 58: "unsigned char data = dataString;" however I changed the string to have a null termination and added a loop to the calling of putByte but I'm still getting a segfault. There are no compile errors now.

Comment: If you're still getting a segfault, then check the other strings. I didn't hunt down all of them. That's left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I apologize if it was an inconvenience. Would changing the way I clear inputLine and intLine to be a '\0' instead of ' ' be a more appropriate/proper way of clearing them? Is it essentially null?

Answer (score 0):

You should examine your arrays carefully then. By far, the most common error is that either (a) they aren't long enough, or (b) you are calling a function that assumes your string/array is zero (null) terminated, but the zero hasn't been added. A string in C is null terminated for any C string functions to work.

A couple of example trouble spots...

```
47                 char addressString[3];
48                 for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){ //Creates char array of address on current line.
49                      addressString[j] = inputLine[j+4];
50                 }
51                 byteAddress = atoi(addressString); //Turns the array into an int to pass to putByte
```

You are copying 3 bytes from the input line to `addressString`. But this array only has enough space to hold the characters and has no null termination. So the subsequent `atoi` call can go off into never-never land (potential segfault).

Here, `dataString` is an array of characters:

```
53                 unsigned char dataString[12];
54                 for(k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
55                      dataString[k] = (unsigned char)intLine[k+9];
56                 }
57
```

Here, you're treating `dataString` as if it were a single character:

```
58                 unsigned char data = dataString;
59 
60                 if(checkLine(inputLine) == FALSE){
61                     printf("Error on line %d:\n",lineNumber);
62                     printf("%s\n",inputLine);
63                     return 0;
64                 }
65                 
66                 else{
67                     putByte(byteAddress, dataString, &memError);
68                 }
```

This may not cause a segfault, but will certainly be incorrect.